# How to use nodejs with spring mvc

Tags: node.js, spring-mvc, angularjs

I am using spring mvc as a backed in my project and client side is managed by angular js everything is working fine, but now I want to use some socket type of technology in my project so I googled and I found socket.io is commonly used with angularjs but it require node.js for running the app, but currently my project is running into tomcat server which is accessing 8080 port and node.js is in another port so I am facing problem to integrate my project with socket.io and node.js. So please anyone give me some suggestion for this or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Please make proper comment before marking the post as not useful for you or before rating as negative.

Comment: +1 to combat the downvote with no comment.  I agree, a downvote should really be followed with at least a small comment.

Comment: why not go with http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html  or http://async-io.org/